# Find and replace HTML using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, replace, find

I need to use JQuery to find

```
<div class="main-image content-fill" style="display:overflow">
```

in my HTML and replace it with

```
<div class="main-image content-fill" style="display:none">.
```

I would appreciate all help in showing my how to do this. Also, I would like to apply window.onload if possible.

Thanks,

Jared

Comment: `$('.main-image.content-fill').hide()`

Comment: It is better to done with `hide()` then `replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for you.Its similar to the CSS property display:none.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".main-image content-fill").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want only hiding the div use [hide](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_hide.asp) or

use jquery [css classes](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".div1").addClass("important");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".div1").addClass("important");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.important {
   display:none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1">This is some text.</div>
<div id="div2">This is some text.</div>
<br>

<button>Add classes to first div element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main-image.content-fill').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-image content-fill" id="main-image content-fill" style="display:overflow">sdfsdf</div>
```

try this...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-image.content-fill').css('display','none');
});

<div class="main-image content-fill" style="display:overflow">gsdfsf</div>
```